# LyX: How to put temporary files to the lyx-file folder (for TrueCrypt compatibility)

Tags: pdf, lyx, auxiliary-files

I am working on a document in a TrueCrypt volume. As far as I understand, when I view PDF, LyX puts a temporary PDF file (and probably all temporary pdflatex files) into some other folder (at least, I don't see them in the folder with the lyx-file). Can I change this? I would like all files, even those later deleted, to reside in a TrueCrypt folder.

I have tried to remove the path in the Preferences/Paths/Temporary directory, but the PDF file still doesn't appear in the lyx-file folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tmp files and memory dumps are written to disk and those files can be recovered using file system analyses tools such as EnCase/Sleuthkit/Graverobber etc.

If you are working with sensitive data consider using full disk encryption. See this [link](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/09/home-directory-and-full-disk-encryption-in-ubuntu-11-04/) for an overview of of the process.

Comment: If the files were be written to the same TrueCrypt-encrypted directory as the lyx-file, they would be unrecoverable, wouldn't they? In any case, I'm just wondering: Where does LyX puts these files?

Comment: It seems that the placing of tmp files is system dependent e.g. Windows and Linux will save tmp files according to the operating system setup. Data security is a rather involved subject and the easiest solution when working with sensitive data is using data encryption technology to the fullest extend possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the path of the temporary directory (after you set it, restart LyX):

> Tools > Preferences > Paths > Temporary Directory:

[image]